# What is limiting this board to providing 75w

Tags: power-supply

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/PCI-E-to-MXM3-0-Graphics-Card-Raiser-Riser-Card-PCI-Express-X1-to-MXM-3/32953407346.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.7c5c4c4deWJgEZ

the product above is a pcie to mxm adapter. However it is limited to 75 watts. The gpu  I want to put inside uses 150 watts. I was wondering what was restricting it from providing more wattage and if I could modify it to provide more.

Comment: Do you have a circuit diagram or a data sheet (as opposed to a "tell-you-absolutely-nothing-useful-technical" aliexpress website link)?

Comment: Probably something to do with that little 8-pin IC and the 4.7uH inductor next to it. Looks superficially like a SMPS to me.

Comment: The manufacturer might also have opted for the thinnest (cheapest) copper traces, which effectively limits current and therefore power.

Comment: @schadjo Track width does not change the cost. The manufacturer buys a plate completely covered with copper, which is then etched away based on the PCB design. If we want to be really picky, a wide track is cheaper, as there would be less copper to remove, and therefore faster to etch. But that would only make a difference when manufacturing millions of pieces. The limitation is most likely to the component selection, which is likely to be the cheapest, or the specified current limit of the PCI-e connector. Additional power (150W) requires the 8 pin power connector.

Comment: I should've been more clear; I was referring to the depth (1 oz, 2 oz, etc.), not the trace width.

Answer (score 6):

Like with many specifications of products on Aliexpress etc. the specification is **exaggerated**.

This is a photo of the product:

[image]

I notice that it uses a PCI express 1x connector. On the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) I find in the section "Power" this text:

> - ×1 cards are limited to 0.5 A at +12 V (6 W) and 10 W combined.
> - ×4 and wider cards are limited to 2.1 A at +12 V (25 W) and 25 W combined.
> - A full-sized ×1 card may draw up to the 25 W limits after initialization and software 
>     configuration as a "high power device".
> - A full-sized ×16 graphics card[13] may draw up to 5.5 A at +12 V (66 W) and 75 W 
>     combined after initialization and software configuration as a "high power device".

So this 1x card can only draw at most 25 W **if** it would configure itself as a "high Power device". The circuit on the PCB to me looks like a DCDC converter and not a circuit which can do the "high power device" configuration. So then we're limited to 6 W!

*So where does the 75 W come from?*

My guess is that is the power that can be used when a PCI-E card has an **additional power connector**, many graphics cards have these. This 75 W is **not** coming from the PCI-E slot!

So if the MXM card you intend to use with this adapter does **not** have an external power connector (I expect that to be a 12 V input) then you cannot use that with this adapter.

Another issue will be **cooling**, a 150 W graphics chip / board will need **serious** cooling so a large heatsink, heatpiples and one or more fans. MXM graphics cards are designed to be used in laptops where the cooling is an integral part of the design of the laptop. That is not so if you use the MXM card in this adapter.

I think you will be wasting your money if you buy this card as it is very likely that it will simply **not work**.